# How can I debug Google Chrome extension written by third party?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension

I want to understand where a particular extension is loading its data from.
I also want to prevent this extension from sending private data to Google Analytics (regardless of how this sounds, this is less urgent, but believe it or not, this extension has four stars in Web Store and was rated by 348 people...)

So, back to the more pressing problem: how can I debug / log from the source of this extension?  If I modify the content of this extension, Google Chrome will not load it, because the checksum will not match, so, the easy way of adding `console.log()` seems to be out of question.  What are my options?  Do I have to find the sources of this project from which it was generated (probably not in public domain) and try to go through the motions of recreating this extension, or is there a shortcut?

Comment: You can make a copy of the extension directory, delete _metadata, modify the scripts, and install it as an unpacked extension by drag'n'dropping that directory onto an open chrome://extensions page - it'll replace the webstore version.

Comment: @wOxxOm that would probably work too, but what ErikPerik suggested is easier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to chrome://extensions enable Developer mode amd press the ”.html”-link that appears under the extension name. This will open a console window in the context of the extension background page process.

Note that some extensions doing creepy things might not start doing it until after a set timeout, for example 7 days, to not arouse suspicion from others snooping after installing.